# Load different pictures with combobox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have a problem with combobox2 every time that i choose a item the picture wont load, i want with every selected item in combobox1 the items in combobox2 to change, and with every selected item in combobox2 a different picture to load.

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
            ComboBox2.Text = "Choose Car"
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("car1")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("car2")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("car3")
            If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "car1" Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.BMW

            End If

        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
            ComboBox2.Text = "Choose Truck"
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Truck1")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Truck2")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Truck3")
            If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "Truck1" Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Truck
            End If
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
            ComboBox2.Text = "Choose Bike"
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("bike1")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("bike2")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("bike3")
            If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "bike1" Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Bike
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: You can't compare `ComboBox2.SelectedItem (an object) =  "bike1"`, a string. I mean you can compare but that's not what you want. You will instead want to compare `ComboBox2.SelectedItem.Text = "bike1".`

Comment: and btw, where have you put the code you have mentioned? Under which event?

Comment: i did it but im getting this error: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object variable or With block variable not set.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: ok wait i've found your problem. i'm posting it as an answer. wait a few min just.

Comment: i have bot put the code in any event just playing around :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code is that when you are checking for selected items in ComboBox1, you add new items to ComboBox2 but at the same time you immediately check for selected items in ComboBox2. This means, you do not get time to select anything in ComboBox2. This will inevitably throw an exception since nothing is selected.

So what you could do is respond to ComboBox1 Selection Changed Events and add new items to ComboBox2 accordingly and then in a separate Event Handling Sub, load pictures to the pictureBox according to selection in ComboBox2. This code will work for you -

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Text = "Choose Car"
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("car1")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("car2")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("car3")


    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Text = "Choose Truck"
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Truck1")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Truck2")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Truck3")

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Text = "Choose Bike"
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("bike1")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("bike2")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("bike3")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "car1" Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.BMW
    End If
    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "Truck1" Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Truck
    End If
    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "bike1" Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Bike
    End If
End Sub
```